Why can't thin clouds form rainbows?
Sunlight easily passes through THIN layers of clouds, composed of small water droplets/vapor, what is the problem accounted by the light rays that they are not able to form a rainbow?

What do you mean by thin?  I'd say that the mist from my garden hose is thin, and I can certainly see rainbows when I'm watering the plants.

There is no problem. It is called "halo" and you can see a tiny circular rainbow on the photo.

Clouds are complicated. There are lots of different types of clouds, which may be composed of spherical or non-spherical water droplets, with uniform or non-uniform sizes; planar or columnar ice crystals; snowflakes or hailstones; there are probably other options.  Clouds also display a number of different types of colorful optical phenomena, such as sundogs, circum-horizon or -zenith arcs, 22º and 44º halos, light pillars, coronae, and iridescence, to name a few.  There is a whole science of modeling atmospheric optical displays in order to figure out what shape of ice crystals or water droplets are in the sky when those phenomena are observed.
The classic rainbow, including the "double rainbow" if the second-order refraction is visible, comes from water refracting through spherical drops.  The third- and fourth-order rainbows appear in the direction of the sun; the rare fifth-order rainbow winds up between the first- and second-order.
A bright primary rainbow requires sunlight to be reflected from many droplets, and also for the reflected sunlight to escape back in the sunward direction towards the observer.  A light rain, where you can see through the rain to the hills a kilometer or more away, is a good condition for a rainbow.  The conditions are improved in the afternoon, if the sun is low at your back in the west and the rain is heavier to your east. This is a common configuration because localized rains tend to be caused by midday heat and tend to move eastward — at temperate latitudes, anyway.
These conflicting requirements for (a) lots of water droplets to generate refraction and (b) enough empty air that the refracted light can travel without re-scattering are part of the reason why the third- and higher-order rainbows are so much rarer than the primary.  After second-order, you have to be in the middle of the rainstorm, but still with the sun clear enough to cast shadows.
Well-defined clouds, like fair-weather cumulus clouds, tend to have shallow "skin" transition from the clear sky to the opaque cloud interior; this is why they have well-defined boundaries.  Iridescent effects in cumulus clouds are most visible in the thin regions around their edges.
You might consider a fogbow as a sort of cloud rainbow, if you consider fog a "ground cloud."  Fog is made of smaller droplets than rain, so that fog droplets remain suspended without the updrafts which support clouds at higher altitudes.  Fog droplets can be small enough that diffraction is non-negligible, blurring out the refractive colors of a rainbow and generating only a sun-colored white arc.

Lots of water droplets is not a requirement to get a visible rainbow: even a simple water spray can produce enough droplets to see a (section of) rainbow. As for fogbow, it (along with glory) appears in normal high clouds too, not only in the fog, and is typically visible when flying by airplane or jumping with a parachute. And actually, this is the real reason why the rainbow due to clouds is not visible (assuming we are looking from above, as we should): it doesn't exist, since the droplets in the clouds are so small that instead we get the fogbow.

All excellent points! Many thanks.

You only see a bright, first-order rainbow when you are looking toward rain or mist and the Sun is behind you. Also, You said, "Sunlight easily passes through thin layers of cloud." That means that not much of the Sun's light is intercepted by the cloud, and therefore, not much is reflected back as a rainbow. Thin clouds will only reflect dimly.
Maybe your best chance to see a rainbow in thin clouds is to fly above them in an airplane when the Sun is high in the sky, and look down on them.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow#/media/File:Circular_rainbow.jpg

As hinted at in the last paragraph of @rob's answer, cloud droplets are simply too small to achieve the diffraction-limited angular resolution needed for the color bands to be distinguishable.
Rainbows are approximately $2\mathrm{{}^{\circ}}$ wide, with each color band being approximately $0.5\mathrm{{}^{\circ}}$ (or $0.01$ radians) wide. According to the Rayleigh criterion, the diffraction-limited resolution of an optical system is given by:
$$
\theta\approx1.22\frac{\lambda}{D}
$$
where $\lambda$ is the wavelength and $D$ is the effective aperture. Solving for $D$ and using a $\lambda$ of $500$ nm (somewhere between blue and green) and a $\theta$ of $0.01$ radians gives:
$$
D\approx1.22\frac{\lambda}{\theta} = 1.22\frac{\lambda}{\theta} = 61\,\mathrm{\mu m}
$$
This means that the cloud droplets would need to be at least $60\,\mathrm{\mu m}$ in diameter in order to resolve the color bands in a rainbow. To resolve them as clearly as normal rainbows, they would probably need to be even larger.
But cloud droplet size distributions typically span the $5$-$50$ $\mathrm{\mu m}$ range, with maxima typically below $20$ $\mathrm{\mu m}$. Rain drops on the other hand, typically have a diameter of $0.5$-$5$ mm, which is large enough for diffraction to be negligible.


Cloud Iridescence is observed when the clouds are thin enough and it can also take the form of corona. From the Wikipedia article:

If parts of clouds contain small water droplets or ice crystals of similar size, their cumulative effect is seen as colors. The cloud must be optically thin, so that most rays encounter only a single droplet. Iridescence is therefore mostly seen at cloud edges or in semi-transparent clouds, while newly forming clouds produce the brightest and most colorful iridescence. When the particles in a thin cloud are very similar in size over a large extent, the iridescence takes on the structured form of a corona, a bright circular disk around the Sun or Moon surrounded by one or more colored rings

